# Make a list out of items in a sublist of a multidimensional list (python)

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

My question is the following:

I have this list: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`
I would like to get this list: `[2, 5, 8]`

This is the second element (`index: 1`) for each sublist in the list of lists.
How could I do this in Python?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Search in Python's doc -> http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: `zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])[1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
M = [y for [x, y, z] in L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use list comprehension:

```
In [88]: l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [89]: [x[1] for x in l]
Out[89]: [2, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Ah... looks easier than I thought! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
a = [x[1] for x in l]
```

Or using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
a = map(lambda x: x[1], l)
```

Or using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) instead of `lambda`, as per the comment below:

```
import operator
a = map(operator.itemgetter(1), l)
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter` is better than `lambda`.